# Deepin 20 and updated Nodejs

Tags: node.js, installation

Does anyone have a solution to get current node / npm versions on Deepin 20?

When trying to install from nodesource I get this:

### Confirming "n/a" is supported...

- curl -sLf -o /dev/null 'https://deb.nodesource.com/node_14.x/dists/n/a/Release'

> Your distribution, identified as "n/a", is not currently supported,
> please contact NodeSource at
> https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/issues if you think this
> is incorrect or would like your distribution to be considered for
> support

Answer (score 8):

Although `Deepin 20.2` can install `Node JS` directly from the `apt`, the version is too old and not maintained anymore.

In addition, the official installation method of `NodeJS` is problematic as it does not support the `Deepin` system.

So you need to look at this script `setup.14.x` to find the actual installation method. Of course, it might be simpler if you already have it installed on `Debian` or `Ubuntu`.

You have to completely uninstall Deepin's own version before installing the official version.

```
sudo apt remove nodejs npm
sudo apt autoremove
```

Add the following content to

`/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list`:

```
deb https://deb.nodesource.com/node_14.x buster main
# deb-src https://deb.nodesource.com/node_14.x buster main
```

Then add the official key and you can install it directly.

```
curl -sSL https://deb.nodesource.com/gpgkey/nodesource.gpg.key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nodejs
```

Problem fixed with Experience.

Comment: This should be marked as the answer. Works fine.

Comment: Works great! No problems!

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked for me to install NodeJS 12. Paste in terminal the following

```
VERSION=node_12.x

DISTRO="$(dpkg --status tzdata|grep Provides|cut -f2 -d'-')"

echo "deb https://deb.nodesource.com/$VERSION $DISTRO main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list

echo "deb-src https://deb.nodesource.com/$VERSION $DISTRO main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

this should work for Deepin 20

Comment: this really helped me! wish i could give you more than +1, just changed to version 18.x


AND
added:
```curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/gpgkey/nodesource.gpg.key | apt-key add -
```
::::::: source : https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/issues/1181#issuecomment-803969479

Answer (score 1):

Deepin isn't listed as a supported distro for NodeSource.

As a Debian derivative, something like this should work:

```
# Using Debian, as root
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | bash -
apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Otherwise you might try a [manual install](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions#debmanual).  If you do, you'll need to specify the `buster` codename since Deepin 20 is based on Debian 10.5.